# Missing argument error when posting data through ajax (using Laravel)

Tags: php, jquery, post, laravel, laravel-3

I'll be precise: I'm having a weird issue with `$.post` jQuery function and an action in my controller. I'm new to PHP, but I've worked with ASP.NET MVC before and I hoped that they were similar. Here is the problem:

```
//This is my ajax call
$.post('get_random_photos', count, function(data) {
    ...
});

//This is my action
public function post_get_random_photos($count) {
    ...
}

//This is what I have in my routes.php
Route::post('photos/get_random_photos', 'photos@get_random_photos');
```

When I make the ajax request, I get the following message:

```
Missing argument 1 for Photos_Controller::post_get_random_photos()
```

I know this could probably be solved using `Input::get('count');` but I'd rather having that `count` as an action parameter, as I used to do in ASP.NET MVC. Is there any way of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your restful route needs to receive that count in the url, this is a way of doing this:

```
//This is my ajax call
$.post('get_random_photos/'+count, 'nothing', function(data) {
    ...
});

//This is my action
public function random_photos($count) {
    ...
}

//This is what I have in my routes.php
Route::post('photos/get_random_photos/(:num)', 'photos@random_photos');
```

Comment: Yes I could do that, but I need my ajax to be a post, any solution?

Comment: The same, actually, just pass a dummy value on post if you don't need to pass any more values than count. Or, as you said, maybe use the Input::get('count'). Edited.

Comment: Almost ok, I needed to change `{count}` by `(:num)`, please fix your answer for further references and I'll accept it.

Comment: Edited and tagged as Laravel 3, I always forget to ask wich version.